# Create a form from XML/ JSON provide functionality to edit the values/attributes and then get the upadated XML/ JSON on submit

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I am trying to find a javascript plugin that can create an HTML form on the basis of XML/JSON structure.

I have multiple records some are XML and some are JSON.
My goal is to provide an XML/JSON representing an object, dynamically generate an HTML form to edit the XML/JSON values, then save the changes back into the XML/JSON obj.

I found a very old similar question in StackOverflow but no answer available.
A sample is available. I kinda want similar functionality.
http://www.datamech.com/XMLForm/

**Looking for a javascript lib for my Angular application that can take XML/ JSON string as input and create an HTML form then return the same XML/JSON with updated values in form of XML/JSON string.**

I can write a function for XML to iterate over the XML(with **DOMParser**) find all the values and attributes, create a form, then bind the values/ attributes back to XML.
But It will be great if I can find an already build a solution like http://www.datamech.com/XMLForm/

Must be solely Javascript.

Must operate completely on the client-side, from input JSON/XML string to edited output JSON/XML string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But what's the question? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I want a javascript plugin to like http://www.datamech.com/XMLForm/ for my angular application that can take an input JSON/XML string to edit( HTML form) and output JSON/XML string.

Comment: I do not want to write everything from scratch as I think this is a very generic requirement, There must be some solutions already build for this.

Comment: Well we're going to do the same as you, google it and paste a link here

Comment: Hi, Jeremy. I searched but got nothing like( http://www.datamech.com/XMLForm/)., will share If I am able to find the solutions :) Thanks